# Is it taboo to encourage or edit answers to be command by command?

Tags: discussion, answers, editing

I'm not sure how many of you get this, but I use a different keyboard  layout (Colemak), and a different vim layout in general, so sometimes when I am reading solutions, I get down right confused because `y` to me is actually `d`, and `<Ctrl-v>` is actually `<Shift-A>`

So it is easier for me when someone breaks up a chain like this:

---

Some Answer:

`<C-v>jy`

---

Some Answer with Command by Command

`<C-v>jy`

- `<C-v>` Visual Block Mode
- `j` Down
- `y` Yank

---

Is it fine if I edit answers to be like this, or is this just annoying, and I should suck it up because these things are not applicable to 99% of people?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your setup. Are you saying you use Colemak on a Qwerty keyboard, so if you want to yank you press the key that is *physically* labelled 'd', but which if you pressed it in (say) notepad/textedit would produce a 'y' character? Is the problem that you touch-type text but finger-peck Vim commands?

Comment: @Rich No; that is not the problem, and a curse upon anyone who is chicken pecking vim commands. Its more like, if you do not remap colemak back to something resembling default vim physical layout, your directional keys get really annoying really fast. Remapping to original layout would put the directional keys on `neio`. https://colemak.com/wiki/images/8/80/Colemak_layout_2.png

Make sense?

Comment: Adding a play-by-play explanation would be good, but simply breaking up a long macro would be more likely to confuse, IMO. So keep the original command and append your edit

Comment: Ah okay. FWIW, there are [at least some advocates](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/5953xg/touch_typists_who_use_jkl_as_the_home_position/d970rgj/) of leaving the standard Vim mappings as they are when using Colemak (and just getting used to the odd hjkl positions). Probably too late for you, if you're already used to your mappings, though :(.

Comment: @Rich Those people, in my humble opinion, are just asking for RSI. You switch to Colemak usually for ergonomic reasons. Vim has the directional keys on the home row for ergonomic reasons. Delegating even one of the most common movement keys to the J is just asking for trouble. Not to mention it is slower.

Comment: I think a lot of answers containing macros already have this kind of explaining (I can quote [one of mine](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/8911/1841) or one of [nobe4's](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4396/1841)). Now is it worth editing all of the answer which doesn't have this formalism? I'm really not sure that's worth the trouble.